# Mockito with void method

Tags: mockito

I want to test method returning the void.
What i should correct ?

```
public class ServicesTest 
{
@Mock
ClientDao clientDaoMock;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
ClientService clientService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
//FixMe
@Test
public void saveClient() {
    when(clientDaoMock.saveClient(any(Client.class))).thenReturn(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should interact with your mock in the test method, either directly or indirectly through your `clientService`. You got the exception in your comment because there were no calls to `saveClient` during the test.

After that, you can verify if a method is called with specific parameters. It should look something like the following:

```
@Test
public void saveClient() {
   // Any interaction with the mock, like:
   clientDaoMock.saveClient(aClient)
   verify(clientDaoMock, times(1)).saveClient(any(Client.class));
}
```